# Configure Azure Container Insights so that metrics are not sent to Log Analytics Workspace?

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-kubernetes-service

I want to configure my Container Insights monitoring on my AKS cluster so that only Container Insights logs and not metrics are sent to my log analytics workspace. I still want metrics to be collected but I want them to be sent to azure monitor.

I have tried creating a cluster in Terraform with the oms_agent block and with msi_auth_for_monitoring_enabled set to false.

I also created a Data Collection rule in terraform which sends "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics" to the "azure_monitor_metrics" destination, however in the portal the data collection rule has no data source listed. I manually created one for Performance Counters to the azure monitor metrics however that did not achieve the desired result as I can still run Perf queries with Insights metrics against the Log analytics workspace.

I would like to disable all metrics sent to the Log Analytics workspace. The only logs I want are Container Logs.

Is this possible? thanks.